# Auto redirect when timer ends in rails server side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timer

I am making an online examination web-app in rails and I want the user to redirect to a link when the time finishes to end the test (say 25 minutes after start time).

I have implemented a client side countdown timer using [FlipClock.js](http://flipclockjs.com/) which automatically redirects to the end test link when the timer reaches zero. I know the user can turn off javascript in their browser, so I wanted a server side solution which does something similar.
I am storing `start_time` in my database.

Comment: I can't think of anyway to do this on the server side because of the way the request loop works in rails. On the server side you could not accept results if the results are submitted after "start_time + 25mins + buffer". On the client you could not display the test if JS is turned off. Having the client redirect is a nice connivence but the test will need to be secured on the server-side because you can't trust the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can redirect any user who reloads the page (or submits the test) after 25 minutes to that link. But I'm afraid you cannot redirect user in the middle of the test without any JS.

p.s. you can always consider banning the test for JS-disabled browsers.